# How to show random record using wp functionality

Tags: wordpress

I working on wordpress site .In sidebar there is section `Recent News`.That contain 4 recent news.I want that its will change after refreshing page.

I have created a category name `News` After that inserted 10 post and select `News` category for all 10 post.
And through wp code show 4 recent post in sidebar.But  i want that it will change when i refresh page.PLease help me if any body have any idea.I am using the code below

```
    <h1>
      <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon1.jpg" alt=""  />&nbsp;Recent News
    </h1>
    <?php

    global $post;
    $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4','category=5');
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong> <br />
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <h3><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/sapration1.jpg" alt="" /></h3>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Through Query I know how its possible but in wordpress how i do.In query this is possible with  `RAND()` function.

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `wp_testimonials` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,2");

PLease reply me asap.I shall be very thankful to u

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friend i got the solution.

```
  <h1><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/icon1.jpg" alt="" />&nbsp;Recent News</h1>       
 <?php $recent = new WP_Query("cat=5&showposts=4&orderby=rand");
                        while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post(); ?>
                      <p><strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong> <br />

                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    <h3><img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/sapration1.jpg" alt="" /></h3>
           <?php endwhile; ?>
```